# Gmail SMTP relay will not allow connection with PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, smtp

For reference, i am using PHPMailer 6+,php5.6, Mysql.
For a week, every day, I have been trying to send a simple confirmation email to my clients. Every attempt fails with this code..

```
2020-12-17 03:16:09 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP l191sm2541398qke.7 - gsmtp
2020-12-17 03:16:09 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO mylocalstores.ca
2020-12-17 03:16:10 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [99.237.166.96]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
2020-12-17 03:16:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
2020-12-17 03:16:10 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
2020-12-17 03:16:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden]
2020-12-17 03:16:10 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
2020-12-17 03:16:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden]
2020-12-17 03:16:10 SERVER -> CLIENT: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials l191sm2541398qke.7 - gsmtp
2020-12-17 03:16:10 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials l191sm2541398qke.7 - gsmtp
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
2020-12-17 03:16:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2020-12-17 03:16:10 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection l191sm2541398qke.7 - gsmtp
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Mail FAIL.. SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

This is the code i used to send

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
require 'src/Exception.php';
require 'src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'src/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

//gmail loggin
$mail->username = 'mylocalstores.ca@gmail.com';
$mail->password = '*hidden*';

$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Port = 465;

$mail->Subject = 'Test Email from me';
$mail->Body = '<h1>Hello Gmail</h1>';
$mail->setFrom("autonut66@gmail.com","admin");
$mail->addAddress("mylocalstores.ca@gmail.com","user");
if($mail->Send()){
    echo 'Mail Sent.. ';
}else{
    echo 'Mail FAIL.. '. $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

This is becoming very irritating.
I have tried an app code, reducing my security, allow less secure apps.
I have checked my IP against blacklists( no flags ).
I tried using 587/TLS
nothing seems to work. Do i own the email part of my domains ( i have 12 sites on my server), or must i pay extra for it.
i need this to work. y whole register system depends on email for confirmation and communication.

is there other options? i do not see the point of hosting my own server if i cannot send emails. Signup scripts and communication is primarily done with email. Seems like a catch-22 situation. Either way, u will pay more.

do i need to SSL my whole server? or mod-proxy... self-sign... etc...

hMail server seems like an option... but how do i wrestle control for my email address from Godaddy..

insights, suggestions, or help is much appreciated.

Comment: The error message references: https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials did you try going there and following those instructions?

Comment: i have been to that page multiple times. i tried every configuration they have shown. all pop, imap,smpt fiields are open

Comment: And you enabled the "Less Secure Apps" as recommended here? https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: yes. Even tried contacting google to find out what the issue was. My credentals are correct. i use the same password to sign in. i have tried at least 10 different app passwords over the past week